# Ruby stub a Dir.glob with Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, stub

I want to test with rspec my class Episode, which take a string in constructor that will determine the episode number, search for the episode subtitle file with the corresponding episode number and set the subtitle name of the episode.

The problem I am facing is that I do not want to test with real files neither with a creation of fake files (already did it and it is working fine).

I believe I need to stub the call to Dir.glob but so far I have been unlucky.

Any ideas ?

```
class Episode
  attr_reader :avi_file, :subtitle_name, :number, :name, :directory

  # an episode is instantiated with an avi filename
  def initialize(avi)
    @name = File.basename(avi, ".avi")
    @directory = File.dirname(avi)
    # Looking for an episode number in the form of 
    # s01e01 or 01x01
    match_data = @name.match /(s\d{2,}e\d{2,}|\d{2,}x\d{2,})/i
    @number = match_data.to_s
    find_subtitle_in
    puts self.subtitle_name
  end



  private

  def find_subtitle_in
    srt_files = Dir.glob("#{@directory}/*.srt")
    @subtitle_name = srt_files.find { |e| /#{@number}/i =~ e }
  end

end
```

---

**Specs**

```
 it "does find a subtitle" do
    episode = Episode.new "Friends s01e01.avi"
    Dir.stub!(:glob){["Friends.s02e01 subtitle french.srt", "Friends.s01e01 subtitle french.srt" ]}
    episode.subtitle_name.should == "Friends.s01e01 subtitle french.srt"
  end
```

---

**Outputs of rspec**

1) Episode does find a subtitle
     Failure/Error: episode.subtitle_name.should == "Friends.s01e01 subtitle french.srt"
       expected: "Friends.s01e01 subtitle french.srt"
            got: nil (using ==)
     # ./spec/lib/episode_spec.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in '

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
it "does find a subtitle" do
    Dir.stub!(:glob){["Friends.s02e01 subtitle french.srt", "Friends.s01e01 subtitle french.srt" ]}
    episode = Episode.new "Friends s01e01.avi"
    episode.subtitle_name.should == "Friends.s01e01 subtitle french.srt"
end
```